# F# Returning the 3 element tuple with the largest middle value from the list of tuples

Tags: list, f#, tuples

I have a homework practice problem and I am new to F# and the syntax is so confusing, I do not know where to start

For example, If I have a list of tuples of increasing values :

`let tupleList = [(1,2,3);(10,12,15);(9,10,20)]`

I should write a function that returns a tuple that has the largest middle value.

So the function should return :

> (10,12,15)

Any hints on what should I consider, read on the Internet, or research, or any other tips to help me learn how to do this is appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should probably read a book on F# or work through https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/

You can use `List.max` or  `List.maxBy` to get the maximum in a list. Because you have a three element tuple, you will need to deconstruct it (as there is no function to access the nth element of a tuple, only the first or the second one). Once you exposed the middle value you can run maxby on it, and get rid of the unnecessary parts.

```
let tupleList = [(1,2,3);(10,12,15);(9,10,20)]

tupleList
|> List.map (fun (a,b,c) -> (b, (a,b,c)))
|> List.maxBy fst
|> snd
```

> val it : int * int * int = (10, 12, 15)

Comment: Unfortunately, i cannot use any built in functions. Thats the restriction that I have on the homework practice.

Comment: You don't need the `List.map`, you can just do: `tupleList |> List.maxBy (fun (_, b, _) -> b)`

Comment: @HenrikHansen indeed! I'm getting a  bit rusty :(  thank you! :D

Answer (score 1):

If none of built-in function can be used, then you can use either (1) mutable variables and while loop or (2) recursion.

Since you are learning functional programming, it is very likely that your professor will prefer recursion. Here is the solution:

```
let max2 (a,b,c) (x,y,z) = if b > y then (a,b,c) else (x,y,z)

let maxMany tuples =
    let rec loop currentMaxTuple remainTuples =
        match remainTuples with
        | [] -> currentMaxTuple
        | tuple :: rest ->
            let newMaxTuple = max2 currentMaxTuple tuple
            loop newMaxTuple rest
    match tuples with
    | [] -> None
    | head :: rest -> Some (loop head rest)

let tupleList = [(1,2,3);(10,12,15);(9,10,20)]
maxMany tupleList |> printfn "%A"
```

Comment: Great!Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different from @Nghia Bui's solution, you can use pattern matching to compare tuples items.

```
let maxSnd tuples = 
    let rec loop list tuple = 
        match list, tuple with
        | [], _ -> tuple
        | (x, y, z) :: xs, (a, b, c) -> 
            if y < b then (a, b, c) else (x, y, z) 
            |> loop xs
    match tuples with
    | [] -> invalidArg "tuples" "Empty list"; 0, 0, 0
    | x :: xs -> loop xs x
```

Answer (score 1):

A little late but anyway:

```
let maxByMiddle data =
    let rec find lst =
        match lst with
        | [] -> Error("No entries in list")
        | [a, b, c] -> Ok(a, b, c)
        | (_, bmax, _)::(a, b, c)::tail when b > bmax -> find ((a, b, c)::tail)
        | maxima::_::tail -> find (maxima::tail)


    find data
```